# How do I make my drupal module have conditional dependencies?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I'm trying to write a module that requires either module a or module b (not both, though having both is fine). It just dependent on a OR b. Is there a way to put this in the .info file or enforce this OR dependency programatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can't natively in any current version of Drupal, there is a [discussion here](http://drupal.org/node/328932) which talks about adding a `enhances[]` and `enhancedby[]` property for `.info` files (amongst a few other new properties), but it has not been put into core as far as I can tell.

If you're using Drupal 6 you might have a look at the [Module Supports](http://drupal.org/project/module_supports) module which was created in response to that discussion.

If you're using Drupal 7 the discussion might get you half way there, and if not there are a few patches on that page that will at least show you roughly what you need to do to patch Drupal core yourself to do get it working.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've seen other modules implement this is by reporting problems after a module is installed and not including the modules as dependent. I would assume this would be similar to modules like ckeditor or jquery_ui which require non-drupal code to be put in place to operate properly.